# Is there any phrase similar to "may he rest in peace"?

Tags: set-phrases

George Michael just passed away... is there any phrase analogous to "may he rest in peace"? To me at least, that English phrase is emotionally tinged. I mean, I really do feel sad. But of course, I'd never say that phrase regarding the death of a family member because "may he rest in peace" is a little too distant.

So, is there any Japanese phrase that demonstrates genuine respect to someone who just died and who you *didn't* personally know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We usually say...

> 「ご[冥福]{めいふく}をお[祈]{いの}りします。」

or

> 「[安]{やす}らかにお[眠]{ねむ}りください。」

Comment: あ、アイコンが安らかに眠っうわなにするやめｒ

Answer (score 0):

I answer others... They are **not** used commonly!

> - 安らかに眠らんことを.
> - み[霊]{たま}安かれ. (I have never heard this)
> - 安らかに眠りますように.