# How to say "she's dead" or "she passed away"?

Tags: english-to-japanese

How can I say RIP (rest in peace) in Japanese? For example "RIP [name]".

Also, how do I say to someone who know the person "she's dead" or "she passed away this month"?

Comment: The first sub-question "RIP" might be a duplicate of this older post: [Is there any phrase similar to “may he rest in peace”?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41984/15816). The main/second question "is dead/passed away" is unique.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I say RIP (rest in peace) in Japanese?

I think we usually say:

- 「ご[冥福]{めいふく}をお[祈]{いの}りします。」
- 「[安]{やす}らかにお[眠]{ねむ}りください。」

> For example "RIP [name]".

I'm not sure if we have an exact equivalent but how about:

- 「[name]さんのご冥福をお祈りします。」

> Also, how do I say to someone who knows the person "she's dead" or "she passed away this month"?

If she's not in your in-group:

- 「｛彼女は / [name]さんは｝、[今月]{こんげつ}[亡]{な}くなりました。」
- 「｛彼女は / [name]さんは｝、今月お亡くなりになりました。」(politer, more respectful)

If she's in your in-group (family, relative...):

- 「｛彼女は / [name]は｝、[今月]{こんげつ}[亡]{な}くなりました。」
- 「｛彼女は / [name]は｝、今月[他界]{たかい}しました。」

Answer (score 2):

亡くなりました　 closer to 'passed away', than 死ぬ in that it seems to be used in that slightly more sombre respectful tone, and when telling people such news.

eg 昨日おばあさんが亡くなりました。